# Swing: boolean value not changed globally

Tags: java, swing

I am creating my own Button class, extending a JLabel.
My goal is to change its background as soon as the mouse is hovering over it. 
So this is what I got:

```
public String st;
public boolean hover = false, down = false;

public Button() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(hover); // false
            hover = true;
            System.out.println(hover); // true
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(hover); // true
            hover = false;
            System.out.println(hover); // false
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            down = true;
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            down = false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(mainColor());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Color mainColor() {
    return down ? c1 : (hover ? c2 : c3);
    // hover is always false
}
```

For some reason, the boolean values will only change inside the mouse listener.
To make things more confusing, pretty much the same code works perfectly fine in another class.

Comment: "For some reason, the boolean values will only change inside the mouse listener." what does this mean?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual class?

Comment: That is post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem when you ask a question so we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never invoke `repaint()` in your `MouseListener` code, so the `paintComponent()` method will not be invoked.

Whenever you change a property of your custom component you need to invoke `repaint()` to make sure the component is painted in its new state.

> I am creating my own Button class, extending a JLabel.

Why would you extend JLabel just to paint a background? You should be extending JPanel or JComponent.

If you need more help (and in the future when you ask a question) post a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.